# Is there maximum number of points you can import from CSV to QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, csv, qgis-2, mac

I tried to import a CSV file which contains 4,783 rows. However, only 20 records appeared. Any one has solutions to solve this situation? How can I add all rows in QGIS delimited layer?

PS: I use Mac 10.10.5, QGIS 2.18.0, GDAL/OGR 2.1.2.

Comment: sounds like an import error (like header doesn't match attributes).

Comment: It's unlikely that you're hit a maximum at twenty features. It's far more likely that a parse failure has occurred.  Please [Edit] your question to provide greater detail on your import process and provide a sample of CSV rows which succeeded and failed. Don't forget to take the [Tour].  And welcome to GIS SE.